# Can we use android studio app for azure mobile service?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to use Mobile Service for Android app that is developed through google Android studio ? Or is it compulsory to developed a mobile app thru xamarin only ???

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/ 3 seconds of googling. Literally

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure Mobile Services with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620698/azure-mobile-services-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Xamarin, although that is a good option if you are familiar with the .Net Microsoft environment.
You can get started with native Android (via Android Studio) development here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/